# Longitud media de las frases en español

Tags: lingüística

Los hablantes nativos de español, al hablar inglés a menudo tenemos que dividir una frase larga en varias cortas, dado que en ese idioma las frases largas quedan un poco forzadas.

Me pregunto si la posibilidad de construir frases largas es una característica del español, de las lenguas romances en general, o si es el inglés el que supone una excepción al no permitir frases complejas.

Las estadísticas podrían ser una buena ayuda para conocer lo anterior. Actualmente, con la fuerza que está cobrando el *Big Data*, pienso que debería haber bastantes personas realizando trabajos estadísticos con las lenguas. ¿Puede alguien aportar la longitud media de las frases en español y compararlas con los mismos datos obtenidos de otras lenguas?

En particular, creo interesantes 2 **comparaciones de la longitud media de las frases** en:

1. Español frente a alguna lengua romance: Francés, por ejemplo.
2. Español frente a inglés.

Comment: Mmm, yo no divido frases largas en cortas. ¿Algún ejemplo?

Comment: Interesante pregunta, pero al ser tan difusa y amplia en cuanto a la comparación con otras lenguas, es propensa a ser cerrada como "too broad". No le veo problema a "Cuál es la longitud media de las frases en español?". Ni siquiera a la comparación con otra lengua "Es mayor o menor la longitud media que X ?" Pero comparar con una cantidad no definida de lenguas tampoco definidas hace que la pregunta sea dificil de contestar bien.

Comment: @Diego De acuerdo contigo, no es un problema: Es una duda o más bien una curiosidad. Voy a corregir la pregunta para que sea más concreta y evitar el cierre por "too broad"

Comment: FWIW, in English the average sentence length seems to be between [15 and 20](https://strainindex.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/the-average-sentence-length/) words.

Comment: @Ustanak No te podría dar un ejemplo claro. Tengo la sensación de que mi cuestión en cuatro frases en inglés sería un rollo, pero es una sensación, de ahí que pregunte por números para ver si tiene o no fundamento.

Comment: A mí también me parece una pregunta interesante, pero creo que aun acotando los idiomas a estudiar, se me antoja que intenta abarcar demasiado. Por ejemplo: ¿el estudio es sobre el lenguaje hablado o escrito? Si es sobre el escrito, no es lo mismo un artículo de periódico que una novela que un texto científico. En todos los casos la media de cada tipo de texto te va a dar una cifra diferente.

Comment: Ejemplo a mi anterior comentario: un programa muy sencillo que divide las frases de un texto en inglés buscando los caracteres '.', '?' y '!' me da una media de 18-19 palabras por frase para "Alice's adventures in Wonderland" y "Pride and prejudice", pero de 33 palabras para "On the Origin of the Species". Problema: ¿cómo detectas la longitud de frases que tienen un "Mr. X" a mitad de la misma? El punto de la abreviatura partiría la frase en dos. O frases como _'I wonder how
many miles I've fallen by this time?' she said aloud._, ¿son una frase o dos?

Comment: Me parece que la pregunta es demasiado general. Si preguntas por la longitud media de las frases en castellano, deberías ser más explícito en cuanto a qué define una frase, tal y como comenta @CarlosAlejo Si luego se trata de comparar con otros idiomas, considero que excede el ámbito de este sitio y pasa a ser propio de [linguistics.se].

Answer (score 3):

Iba a poner esto en los comentarios, pero salía demasiado largo. Lo pongo pues como respuesta.

En [Linguist](http://linguistlist.org/ask-ling/message-details1.cfm?asklingid=200433042) ante la pregunta:

> Has there been any research done on the subject of cross-linguistic
>   variation sentence-length? I have been specifically comparing Finnish,
>   German, and English.
>
> More specifically, I am interested in cross-linguistic comparisons of
>   sentence length in formal writing.

Responden:

> (...) There are, however, systematic differences between languages, even
>   between such relatively close relatives as English and Spanish. For
>   example, Spanish tends to often have a comma joining two 'sentences'
>   (clauses) where English would have to have a period. This is standard
>   and acceptable for Spanish. This and other differences mean that
>   sentence length in words tends to be longer in Spanish than in
>   English, so, for example, one has to 'tweak' the readability formulas
>   for English to reflect such differences encountered, in this case, in
>   Spanish.

Lo que sigue también es interesante, pero no lo copio aquí para no hacerlo demasiado largo.

Sin embargo, creo interesante mencionar una parte posterior que tiene parte de "meta" en cuanto a cómo está planteada la pregunta en sí:

> In short, you will have to define very carefully what you mean by
>   'length' (orthographic or according to a phonetic transcription [the
>   latter much harder to count in any sizable corpus, although I think an
>   automatic orthography translator to a phonetic representation should
>   be fairly trivial for Finnish]); these are not the same for most
>   languages.

También es interesante ver la pregunta [Do most languages need more space than English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2998/37429) de [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/). Hay muchas respuestas interesantes, por lo que sugiero leerlas con calma. Me quedo con algún dato:

> Spanish, Portuguese and French (I guess we can just settle on Romance)
>   texts are longer than their English counterparts by about 1/5 to 1/4.

Sin embargo, esto tiene más que ver con la longitud de las palabras que con la de las frases.

Comment: Tengo que reconocer que sí, la pregunta es demasiado genérica. @CarlosAlejo No había caído en lo complejo que puede resultar definir la longitud de una frase, de las diferencias entre hablado y escrito, etc. Creo ahora que intentar reducir el asunto al mero número _"Longitud media de una frase"_ es demasiado simplista.  En cualquier caso, gracias a ambos por las respuestas.

Comment: @Ra_ al respecto de lo último que ha escrito fedorqui en su respuesta, si buscas en Wolfram Alpha el término [Spanish typical translation length](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Spanish+typical+translation+length), obtienes lo que suele ocupar de media un texto en español con respecto a su equivalente en inglés. Lo puedes probar para los idiomas que quieras. Se aleja un poco de lo que quieres investigar, pero no deja de ser un dato curioso.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo is the length of a translation totally relevant here as translating may itself introduce an extra length? Perhaps we need to compare both ways: is a translation into Spanish of Shakespeare as much longer as Lope de Vega into English when each is compared with its original.

Answer (score 2):

Si buscas en [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com) el título de un libro conocido que esté bajo el dominio público, te hace un análisis del mismo. Por ejemplo, si buscas *[On the Origin of Species](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=on%20the%20origin%20of%20species)*, entre otros muchos datos te dice que la longitud media de las frases de ese libro es de 36,38 palabras. La más larga de todo el libro es la que sigue (264 palabras):

> I have attempted to show that the geological record is extremely
>   imperfect; that only a small portion of the globe has been
>   geologically explored with care; that only certain classes of organic
>   beings have been largely preserved in a fossil state; that the number
>   both of specimens and of species, preserved in our museums, is
>   absolutely as nothing compared with the number of generations which
>   must have passed away even during a single formation; that, owing to
>   subsidence being almost necessary for the accumulation of deposits
>   rich in fossil species of many kinds, and thick enough to outlast
>   future degradation, great intervals of time must have elapsed between
>   most of our successive formations; that there has probably been more
>   extinction during the periods of subsidence, and more variation during
>   the periods of elevation, and during the latter the record will have
>   been least perfectly kept; that each single formation has not been
>   continuously deposited; that the duration of each formation is
>   probably short compared with the average duration of specific forms;
>   that migration has played an important part in the first appearance of
>   new forms in any one area and formation; that widely ranging species
>   are those which have varied most frequently, and have oftenest given
>   rise to new species; that varieties have at first been local; and
>   lastly, although each species must have passed through numerous
>   transitional stages, it is probable that the periods, during which
>   each underwent modification, though many and long as measured by
>   years, have been short in comparison with the periods during which
>   each remained in an unchanged condition.

Y eso a pesar de que la recomendación en inglés es de no superar las 20 palabras por frase y usar siempre las palabras más cortas posibles. En el caso de la [Biblia](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=bible), la longitud media de las frases es de 23,34 palabras, algo más acorde con lo que se espera de un texto dirigido al público en general (la frase más larga tiene en este caso 90 palabras). Curiosamente, las obras de Shakespeare, que representan más fielmente el inglés hablado al ser obras de teatro, tienen una media de unas 15 palabras por frase (al menos [Romeo y Julieta](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Romeo%20and%20Juliet) y [Hamlet](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=hamlet), las dos que he consultado).

Lo malo: que me está resultando difícil encontrar obras analizadas en español, por lo que no puedo hacer comparaciones. He probado con el Quijote, pero nada, y más famoso que eso... En todo caso, tu duda de si el inglés no permite construir frases largas creo que ha quedado disipada con el ejemplo. ;-)

Comment: Using the mean length (which is how I translate media) is fraught with problems if the lengths are very skewed (a long tail with a few long sentences). The median might be more helpful.